# tablesorter custom group header with pattern

Tags: tablesorter

I am looking for a solution like `[this][1]`.

But the group header would be different to grouped column contents. For example I would like group header be " approved" if the column  contents are 2a,2b,2c etc. I tried using "group-letter-1" but the header comes in as 2(3).

Looks like i need to use group-header call back function, but don't know how to incorporate regex pattern.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry here is the link : `[http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1441/]`

Comment: Please provide some example HTML.. the demo doesn't have 2a,2b,2c, etc. Also, what values would constitute being "approved"?